# How can I to make surfaceview invisible in Android?

Tags: android, surfaceview, seekbar

in my app i am using a media player with a seek bar. The seek bar of works along with a surface view. Now my problem is the surface view appears at a corner of my layout which appears to be a black screen. How can i make the surface view to be an invisible. Following is the image of my layout,

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that by setting the visibility in the code:

`surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `surfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

And you can do the same by setting it in the XML:

```
<SurfaceView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:visibility="gone"/>
```

GONE is used if you want it to be completely gone and ignored by the rest of the layout. INVISIBLE is used if you only want to change the visibility.

Comment: Note that setting the visibility of a SurfaceView to INVSIBILE or GONE will destroy the surface view if it has already been created.

Answer (score -1):

you can use surfaceView.setVisibility*(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Note that setting the visibility of a SurfaceView to INVSIBILE or GONE will destroy the surface view if it has already been created.